# Hat on Winter Bash profile gone after refresh

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

The profile in the [Winter Bash site](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com) doesn't wear a hat after a refresh of the page, presumably due to a bug that sets both the width and height of the hat to `0px`. I'm using Safari 11.0.1.

[image: 2017]

```
<div class="hat" style="float: left; display: block; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: visible; position: relative; left: 24px; top: 0px;" data-hatid="10">
                                                            ^ 0px?       ^ 0px?
    <img src="some_svg" width="0" height="0" style="display: block;">
                               ^ 0px?     ^ 0px?
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm. The 0px size on the `div` is correct, but not on the `<img>`. Is this still happening? With (or rather, without) the hat you're currently wearing?

Comment: @balpha The hat only displays when I go directly to the WB page in a new tab/window and disappears after a refresh. Seems to be the case for all hats.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

No Repro from what I can tell. You *should* be seeing a hat.

Comment: Does it still wear the hat if you refresh the page?

Comment: @Panda yep. I concur... It takes a half second to pop in, but it does come in... even after a refresh.

Comment: @Catija Mine doesn't seem to come in at all

Comment: Hmmm... let me check Safari... works fine in Safari... but I'm using 9.

Comment: @Catija I think it occurs on newer versions, I'm able to reproduce it on both of my computers running Safari 11

Comment: [I can’t see any difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADCZ9.jpg)

Comment: Sure there is. There's a hat on my hat.